# Slider background in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider, label

First I made a picture of my problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdawJ.jpg

You have 3 sliders and they all need a background color. Maybe the 3 labels below need a background color too.

```
GUI.color = Color.white;
```

Does not seem to help much. I need this black background for the simulation so i need to make the slider background white...

But GUILayout and GUISkin do not have properties for this, no? I can not find something useful there...

The components i use:

GUI.HorizontalSlider + GUI.Label

Comment: I recommend using the newer and more versatile Canvas system for laying out UI.  OnGUI is legacy, but I do still use it for prototyping and debug tools.

Comment: Yes, but i want to script it because i feel better with it. I can see my results there. In the editor i always have to click and search around for it :/

Answer (score 0):

Within a [GUI Skin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html), there is a Horizontal Slider property.  That property has [GUI Style](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUIStyle.html) properties of Normal, Hover, Active, and Focused.  You should set a background to all 4 of those elements.

Here's an example using programmatically-created GUIStyle (tested with Unity 5.4.2p4). Note that when creating a fresh GUIStyle, you need to assign dimensions, or it might not be visible.

```
public class MySliderIMGUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GUIStyle _sliderBackgroundStyle;
    private GUIStyle _sliderThumbStyle;
    private float _sliderValue = 0f;
    private Texture2D _whitePixel;
    private Texture2D _blackPixel;

    void Start()
    {
        this._whitePixel = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        this._whitePixel.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.white);
        this._whitePixel.Apply();

        this._blackPixel = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        this._blackPixel.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.black);
        this._blackPixel.Apply();

        this._sliderBackgroundStyle = new GUIStyle();
        this._sliderBackgroundStyle.padding = new RectOffset(2, 2, 2, 2);
        this._sliderBackgroundStyle.normal.background = this._whitePixel;
        this._sliderBackgroundStyle.hover.background = this._whitePixel;
        this._sliderBackgroundStyle.active.background = this._whitePixel;
        this._sliderBackgroundStyle.focused.background = this._whitePixel;

        this._sliderThumbStyle = new GUIStyle();
        this._sliderThumbStyle.stretchHeight = true;
        this._sliderThumbStyle.fixedWidth = 20f;
        this._sliderThumbStyle.normal.background = this._blackPixel;
        this._sliderThumbStyle.hover.background = this._blackPixel;
        this._sliderThumbStyle.active.background = this._blackPixel;
        this._sliderThumbStyle.focused.background = this._blackPixel;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        this._sliderValue = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(100, 100, 200f, 20f), this._sliderValue, 0, 1, this._sliderBackgroundStyle, this._sliderThumbStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code example for a background setting? I dont get it for labels and sliders ...

Comment: Thank you very much! Can i try this code for a label background too?

Comment: Yes, this should work for anything that uses a GUIStyle.